# Is there a way to know if a window is in a different browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if there is a way to know if a window has been opened in a different browser instance or if It has been dragged out of the browser which opened it.
I'm using `window.open()` to open a new tab, but it depends on browser config, so I need to know if the child page is on the same browser window than it's father.

I also thought to check the window size and compare it to the parent, if the user undocks and then maximazes the window the size will be the same as it's parent window size, so it doesn't work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: The answer will be no

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean by window opened in a different browser instance.  This could be interpreted in many ways.  ?If you are using window.open - you will have a reference to the opened window.  Until the user redirect it away to another URL domain other than what it was opened with, you can check the window size to see if it is the same as the parent window size,  this would indicate the window had been undocked?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to access this information.  However, if you can explain what you are trying to use this for and what you have tried towards accomplishing your goals, someone here may be able to help solve the underlying problem in a different way.